# jstree + json - array elements coming in under same list element

Tags: json, jquery, jstree

I'm a sysadmin doing some web dev work, so I don't exactly have tons of Javascript experience.

Right now I'm trying to build a tree using jstree, but all of my elements are ending up inside the same

tags.  Specifically:

```
<ul>
    <li class="jstree-last jstree-leaf">
        <ins class="jstree-icon"> </ins>
        <a id="23" href="#">
            <ins class="jstree-icon"> </ins>
            a node
        </a>
        <a id="24" href="#">
        <ins class="jstree-icon"> </ins>
            another node
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

My javascript looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#containersTypesTree").jstree({
        json_data : {
            ajax : {
                type : 'POST',
                url : "ajax.php",
                dataType : 'json',
                data : function() {
                    return {
                        action : 'getTree'
                    }
                },
            success : function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                return data;
            }
        }
    },
    plugins : [ "themes", "json_data" ]
    });

 });
```

The JSON that's being kicked out looks like this:

```
{"data":[{"title":"a node","attr":{"id":"23"},"children":[]},{"title":"another node","attr":{"id":"24"},"children":[]}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, JSON needed to look like this:

```
**{"data":[{"title":"a node","attr":{"id":"23"},"children":[]},{"title":"another node","attr":{"id":"24"},"children":[]}]}**
```